# vCenter Heartbeat cluster Windows updates

Tags: vmware-vcenter

We're in the planning stage of implementing vCenter Server Heartbeat in a P2P environment. The servers will be based in the same datacenter so they will be configured as a "LAN" type. I'd like feedback on how others are dealing with windows patching as the servers share the same name/IP addressing.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We ditched the, very expensive, heartbeat in exchange for simply HA'ing the VC VMs - we can live with the restart time - you may not be able to.

As for patching, well it's easier than you'd think, just take one VC down, patch it, bounce it, let them sync again, wait a while then repeat for the second VC. It's that simple.